# Regex to match ampersand between two single-letter words

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace ampersand when it is found between two single-letter words.

Given below is the regex I use, but it is matching words consisting or two or more letters, too.

`([A-Za-z]{1})((\s&\s)|(&)|(\s&)|(&\s))([A-Za-z]{1})`

On top of that, there might be spaces between either of the letters.

E.g.:

1. A &B Should be replaced as AB
2. A& B Should be replaced as AB
3. A&B Should be replace as AB
4. ALPHA & B should not be matched. (Since ALPHA is a word)
5. ALPHA & BETA Should not be matched. (Since ALPHA & BETA both are words)

Comment: Try `"(?<=\\p{L})&(?=\\p{L})"` or `"(?<=[A-Za-z])&(?=[A-Za-z])"`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part of your reply. `^[a-zA-Z]{1}&[a-zA-Z]{1}$` seems to work just fine: it matches `A&B`. You could, then, use a String method to replace the `&` with `''`.

Comment: Or, `"(?<=\\b\\p{L})&(?=\\p{L}\\b)"` / `"(?<=\\b[A-Za-z])&(?=[A-Za-z]\\b)"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AH7wy/1))

Comment: Thanks for the Regex..@WiktorStribiżew... it is working for Example 3 where as I need single regex to match first 3 Examples.

Comment: Ok, `s.replaceAll("(\\b[A-Za-z])\\s*&\\s*(?=[A-Za-z]\\b)", "$1")` (`[A-Za-z]` may be replaced with `\\p{Alpha}` or `\\p{L}`)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew...Its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String result = s.replaceAll("(\\b[A-Za-z])\\s*&\\s*(?=[A-Za-z]\\b)", "$1")
```

Note: `[A-Za-z]` may be replaced with `\\p{Alpha}` (to match any ASCII letter) or `\\p{L})` (to match any Unicode letter).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AH7wy/2). **Details**

- `(\b[A-Za-z])` - Group 1: a word boundary and a letter
- `\s*&\s*` - a `&` enclosed with 0 or more whitespace chars
- `(?=[A-Za-z]\b)` - a positive lookahead (to allow overlapping matche) that requires a letter followed with a word boundary immediately to the right of the current location.

To keep the first one-letter word in the result, the replacement pattern contains `$1` placeholder.